# How do I delete all of my recent Google searches forever?

Tags: google-search-history

Every week Google clears my searches. But I want to delete it every day so when I come back the next day my recent searches are gone.

Comment: How do you set that Google clearas your searches? What you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want a manual process, semi-automatic process or a completely automatic process? I am not so sure if there is a automatic process for something less than 3 months though.